# Change image with only jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change an image from an old to new using jquery or javascript only. It is the second picture out of three total that has a common parent element and is not separated by any specific parameters.

I believe I need to use a DOM navigation of some sort to get to the exact picture in the common class but haven't had any luck.

As I mentioned the 'make' class is shared between all three images as is 'make-image'. I need to simply swap the image for another updated version, facebook1.jpg.

```
<li class="make ">
        <a href="#">
        <img class="make-image" src="facebook.jpg">
        <div class="make-info">
            <img class="make-logo" src="facebook.jpg">
                <div class="clearall"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>

It should simply swap the existing image for another.
```

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for the image tags inside the list-item and iterate with `each` over the returned array. Inside that loop you can check if the src of that image-element is what you are looking for and replace it.

```js
$('li.make img').each(function(index){
  if ($(this).attr('src') == 'facebook.jpg') {
    $(this).attr('src', 'facebook1.jpg');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="make">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="make-image" src="facebook.jpg">
    <div class="make-info">
      <img class="make-logo" src="facebook.jpg">
      <div class="clearall"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```